# How long are Google Static Map custom markers cached for?

Tags: caching, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How long are [Google Static Map custom markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#CustomIcons) cached for?

When setting a custom marker and then changing it (eg, using the same file name but a different image) it seems to cache the first file used. This is awkward when tweaking a design.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no policy for this (so it may change without notice) - right now they seem to expire in 1 day.

Requesting http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|996600 returned the following headers

```
Date          Tue, 16 Nov 2010 00:35:41 GMT
Expires       Wed, 17 Nov 2010 00:35:41 GMT
Cache-Control public, max-age=86400
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass extra parameters to the static maps API if you want to, Google will just ignore them and you can use it for cachebreaking. We did this all the time for testing in a place I used to work.

Usually we tagged the time onto the url in the request, and it'd prevent it from being cached:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|996600&time=1290371937

Or set your web browser to stop caching images while you're testing.

Comment: Very old answer, but this doesn't seem to work anymore. Have you tried this recently?